# Image goes under Text

Tags: css

I dont understand how to fix this.

Whenever I am on a mobile or tablet view the image goes under the text and it makes the words unreadable. It looks amazing on laptop/computer view but horrible on mobiles or tablets. This is my website. http://www.phincer.com/ Its the part that has the heading "We Know How Important A WEbsite Is For Your Company" Here is the code.

```
    .style_two {
    position: relative;
}
    .style_two .promo-image {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    text-align: right;
    background: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden
}
    .style_two .promo-image img {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
    .style_two .caption {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    /*margin-left: 10px;*/
}
```

Comment: make the layout responsive

Comment: its bcz of position absolute .. check screenshot here http://jmp.sh/6j0Jckt

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: You have to use media queries

Comment: @Paulie_D Can you share the code for your comment? I'll favourite it somewhere, I see many questions where this should be the first comment.

Comment: It's a Chrome / FF Extension on Github....you can write your own and add them - https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't set positions correctly. It should be "relative"

Change the following code,

```
<div class="caption wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s">
```

to this,

```
<div class="caption wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s" style="position:relative">
```

or else you can simply change your CSS like following.

```
.style_two .caption {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative !important;
}
```